# How to insert the looping parameter into the middle of a string?

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I am trying to use a bash script to access several files that are in different directories. The directories are numbered, but the numbers appear in the middle of the directory name,

> e.g. histogram1data/ histogram2data/

If I use a for loop to read these directories, it does not work:

```
#bash script

for i in {1..100}
  do 

    cd histogram$idata/
    ......code........
    cd ..

 done
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Surround the variable with curly brackets like so:

```
cd histogram${i}data
```

What's happening in your code is bash is trying to interpret the variable `$idata`, which is obviously not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can use curly brackets to delimit the parameter-name:

```
cd "histogram${i}data/"
```

Incidentally, I recommend wrapping your loop body in parentheses, so it runs in a subshell. This makes it easier to keep track of the current directory, since the `cd` will only have effect inside the subshell. So:

```
for i in {1..100} do 
  (
    cd "histogram${i}data/"
    ......code........
  )
 done
```

Answer (score 2):

bash script:

```
for i in {1..100}
do 
    cd histogram${i}data/
    ......code........
    cd ..
done
```